# How do I retrieve information on specific window from the window manager?

Tags: x11

With X11 how can I out the position and size of a window opened by specific process, preferably by the means of some C or C++ library? The specific window manager in use is `KWin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdotool` is an x11 automation utility and library.

xdotool search --pid

should let you get the list of window identifiers, associated with a specific process if the window manager provides this information in Window Manager Hints. WMs such as `Kwin` or `metacity` do.

`xdotool` provides an API that can be used programmatically.